# Не увеличивается шрифт в Presentation mode в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, шрифты

После установки новой студии в режиме Presentation mode не увеличивается шрифт. Как его увеличить?

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить: что такое *Presentation Mode* в студии?

Comment: @Barmaley, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intellij-idea-viewing-modes.html

Comment: Нда, век живи - век учись :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На англояз. стеке нашел ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287738/decreasing-font-size-of-android-studio-in-presentation. В настройках заходим в Appearance и внизу есть регулировка размера шрифта для Presentation mode.